# UNIX Remove/change file name

Tags: unix

I am trying to do the following in UNIX:
    Everyday I get a new file in the format `ONSITE_EXT_20170707` where the digits represent the date. So the next day I will receive a file ONSITE_EXT_20170708 etc. My goal was to take this file and rename it without the date. I used

```
mv ONSITE_EXT_$(date +%Y%m%d) ONSITE_EXT.
```

However, some days I might not get a new file so I need to do is first check what the latest file(the one with the latest date) is and only rename that file. This should also check if any file is available or not.

Any help is first greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming you are in same dir. where files arrive.

$**cat file_move.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
today_file=ONSITE_EXT_$(date +%Y%m%d)
latest_file=`ls -r|head -1`  #get the latest file in directory
file_part=`echo $latest_file |cut -c1-10`   #get only ONSITE_EXT part of file
    if [ ! -z $today_file ] ; then   #check if today_file variable is not empty i.e. todays file has arrived
        mv ONSITE_EXT_$(date +%Y%m%d) ONSITE_EXT #move the file
    else
        mv $latest_file $file_part  #if todays file isn't arrived. then move latest file only.
    fi
```

Comment: hi syedav, thank you for your help. Can you please explain what the $cat file_move.sh is? Is that part of the solution? Also, can you please explain whats going on in line 3-5? I really have no experience with UNIX

Comment: $cat file_move.sh is not the part of script. just to display the content of file. Also added comments in almost every step.

Comment: Thanks so much syedav! This is great